# How can I play a video using AVPlayer?

Tags: swift, avplayer

**Apple Swift version 3.0.2 (swiftlang-800.0.63 clang-800.0.42.1)**

I would like to play a video from internet using AVPlayer.
But, a error occurred "super.init(frame: frame)" in AVPlayer.swift of below source list.

> Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16fc07fe0)
>   [image]

How can I play a video using AVPlayer?
If there is wrong point except point of error, let me know it, too.

AVPlayerView.swift

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

final class AVPlayerView : UIView {
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
    override public class var layerClass: Swift.AnyClass {
        get {
            return AVPlayerView.self
        }
    }
```

}

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import CoreMedia

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var playerItem : AVPlayerItem!
    var videoPlayer : AVPlayer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://aaa.com/test.m3u8")!
        let avAsset = AVURLAsset(url: url as URL, options: nil)

        playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: avAsset)

        videoPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)

        print(self.view.bounds)
        let videoPlayerView = AVPlayerView(frame: self.view.bounds)

        let layer = videoPlayerView.layer as! AVPlayerLayer
        layer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect
        layer.player = videoPlayer

        self.view.layer.addSublayer(layer)
        videoPlayer.play()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is code to play video:

```
let videoURL = NSURL(string: "PUT_YOUR_PROPER_URL")
let playerAV = AVPlayer(url: videoURL! as URL)
let playerLayerAV = AVPlayerLayer(player: playerAV)
playerLayerAV.frame = self.view.bounds
self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayerAV)
playerAV.play()
```

AVPlayer support below extension:

```
public.mpeg
public.mpeg-2-video
public.avi
public.aifc-audio
public.aac-audio
public.mpeg-4
public.au-audio
public.aiff-audio
public.mp2
public.3gpp2
public.ac3-audio
public.mp3
public.mpeg-2-transport-stream
public.3gpp
public.mpeg-4-audio
```

Make sure you can use supported video in **AVPlayer**.

Comment: Does AVPlayer support http live streaming of m3u8? HLS includes ts file of H.264 and aac.

Comment: Yes, the URL is changed. A browser of iPhone can play the URL.

Comment: I could play m3u8 video streaming.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to play .mov for the longest time, but it turned out, I also wasn't setting the AVPlayerLayer's frame.